# change src of an img from an XMLHttpRequest

Tags: javascript, html

Using the following script, how can i change the src="#" to src='Poster'

```
var xhttp1 = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhttp4.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (xhttp.readyState == 4 && xhttp.status == 200) {
       var fullMovie = JSON.parse(xhttp.responseText)
       var movie = { poster: fullMovie.Poster};

       document.getElementById('Cover').innerHTML = movie.poster;
    }
 };
 xhttp4.open("GET", "http://www.omdbapi.com/?i=tt3460252&plot=full&r=json", true);
 xhttp4.send();
```

Using this script how can i change the src from the following html?

```
<label for="img1" class="container1">
   <img id="Cover" src="" alt="" class="container1">
</label>
```

Comment: `document.getElementById('Cover').src= movie.poster;`...Use `src` property not `innerHTML`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
document.getElementById('Cover').src = movie.poster
```

Change the src property of the element - you will need to construct a valid url from the data you have if movie.poster is not already a link

Answer (score -1):

using jquery it can be done very easily as:

```
<script>
   $('#Cover').attr('src','Poster');
</script>
```

It will change the value of src attribute of element with id 'Cover'.

But in order to use jquery in your application, you will have to include

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

in head tag.

For more information about jquery visit http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/default.asp